# Function to call the Name of a column in TABLEAU

Tags: tableau-api

I have a problem with Tableau.

I have a Dataset with some rows and some columns. I want to write a IFELSE structure where

The IF condition is that the Value of special field(fixed by a row and a column) is equal to the header of a column (it is every time equal to one name(header) of the different columns).

So to summarize: one value is every time equal to the name of a column and to find the column shall be the if-structure

Does someone know if there is a function to call the name (header) of a column? I didn't find it

Here is an small example, in which the Calculated_function choose the right price according to the Barcode. Everything in the first raw, is the `header_name` of the column below. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJZUG.png)

Best regards

Jonas

Comment: it seems like you have a non relational dataset or something like an excel file which could be a little misleading... could you please share a sample of your dataset?

Comment: Please show your desired output through a sample data

Comment: I added a small example of the Dataset.

Comment: That data sample doesn't make much sense in the format it is given. What would it mean if the column had multiple values in it?

Comment: I changed it now to different values in each column matt_black. The point is that I do not know any function in Tableau which compares the Values in the left columns with the header of the others, which is the idea to calculate the field. best regards

Comment: @clanky1997 have you tried pivoting your columns.  That will convert your colnames to values and thereon you can match the data.  If you want I can show you through an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can work like this.

I created a sample dataset as given by you

[image: Sample_input]

Step-1:  Connected With data in tableau.  Clicked all columns having price (4 here), pivoted them so that they look like this..

[image: After_pivoting]

Step_2: Create calculated_field like this

```
if [Barcode] = [Barcode_c]
then [Price] END
```

Step3: Filtered out null values from calculatedField and got a view like this which can be tweaked as per liking.

[image: Result]